# how to compare multiple array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have mentioned below is two array . compare both array with match Key and there Value have another array of object.if Value is same in both array then filter the array if Value is same in both array then filter the array

````
arr1 =[
    {
        "Key": "Exterior",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Key": "Wheel Covers",
                "Value": "Center Cap"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Coloured Bumpers",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Coloured Outside Door Handles ",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Side Molding",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "High-Mounted Stop Lamp",
                "Value": "yes"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Key": "Interiors",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Key": "Seat Upholstery",
                "Value": "Vinyl"
            },
            {
                "Key": "B & C Pillar Upper Trims",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "C Pillar Lower Trim (Molded)",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Dual-tone Interiors",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent Inside Door Handles",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Center Garnish",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Louvers",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Steering Wheel",
                "Value": "-"
            }
        ]
    }
]```

arr2 =[
    {
        "Key": "Exterior",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Key": "Wheel Covers",
                "Value": "Full"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Coloured Bumpers",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Coloured Outside Door Handles ",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Side Molding",
                "Value": "-"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Key": "Interiors",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Key": "Seat Upholstery",
                "Value": "Fabric+Vinyl"
            },
            {
                "Key": "B & C Pillar Upper Trims",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "C Pillar Lower Trim (Molded)",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Dual-tone Interiors",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent Inside Door Handles",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Center Garnish",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Louvers",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Steering Wheel",
                "Value": "yes"
            }
        ]
    }
]
````

as i have mentioned below in my result.below is my expected result
below is my expected result

````
result= [
{
        "Key": "Exterior",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Key": "Body Coloured Outside Door Handles ",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Side Molding",
                "Value": "-"
            }
        ]
    },
{
"Key":"Interior",
"Value"[
{
                "Key": "C Pillar Lower Trim (Molded)",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Dual-tone Interiors",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
{
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Center Garnish",
                "Value": "-"
            },

]
}
]```

thanks
````

Comment: Please post your work and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear, but it sounds there are probably a lot of duplicates of this. Comparing/merging/filtering arrays of objects is a topic that has been covered (very) extensively in other questions, I'd suggest searching for similar questions to give you ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to filter the data and get result which matches in both arrays. It works as per your expected output.

```js
arr1 =[
    {
        "Key": "Exterior",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Key": "Wheel Covers",
                "Value": "Center Cap"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Coloured Bumpers",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Coloured Outside Door Handles ",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Side Molding",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "High-Mounted Stop Lamp",
                "Value": "yes"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Key": "Interiors",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Key": "Seat Upholstery",
                "Value": "Vinyl"
            },
            {
                "Key": "B & C Pillar Upper Trims",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "C Pillar Lower Trim (Molded)",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Dual-tone Interiors",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent Inside Door Handles",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Center Garnish",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Louvers",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Steering Wheel",
                "Value": "-"
            }
        ]
    }
]

arr2 =[
    {
        "Key": "Exterior",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Key": "Wheel Covers",
                "Value": "Full"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Coloured Bumpers",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Coloured Outside Door Handles ",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Body Side Molding",
                "Value": "-"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Key": "Interiors",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Key": "Seat Upholstery",
                "Value": "Fabric+Vinyl"
            },
            {
                "Key": "B & C Pillar Upper Trims",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "C Pillar Lower Trim (Molded)",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Dual-tone Interiors",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent Inside Door Handles",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Center Garnish",
                "Value": "-"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Louvers",
                "Value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Silver Accent on Steering Wheel",
                "Value": "yes"
            }
        ]
    }
]


let result = arr1.map(x=> {
    return {
        ...x,
        Value: x.Value.filter(v => {
            return arr2.find(a2 => {
                return a2.Value.find(av => {
                    return v.Key == av.Key && v.Value == av.Value
                });
            })
        })
    }
})

console.log(result)
```